# Let Composer place a Git repo into a custom path

Tags: composer

How to place git repo to a custom path? I am using composer/Installer. and I have develop a module on git repo. I would like to add it to composer.json but after pull it should be placed web/modules/custom directory. How can i do that.

I added this parts in my composer.json

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/miteshmap/axelerant_custom"
    }
],

"require": {
    "miteshmap/axelerant_custom": "*"
},
"extra": {
    "installer-paths": {
        "web/core": ["type:drupal-core"],
        "web/modules/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-module"],
        "web/modules/custom/{$name}": ["type:drupal-module"],
        "web/profiles/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-profile"],
        "web/themes/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-theme"],
        "drush/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-drush"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"require": {
    "composer/installers": "dev-master",
    "miteshmap/axelerant_custom": "*"
},
"extra": {
    "installer-paths": {
        "web/core": ["type:drupal-core"],
        "web/modules/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-module"],
        "web/modules/custom/{$name}": ["type:drupal-custom-module"]
        "web/profiles/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-profile"],
        "web/themes/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-theme"],
        "web/themes/custom/{$name}": ["type:drupal-custom-theme"]
        "drush/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-drush"],
    }
}
```

We can do that when composer/installers have defined the type and for that a request was merged with master here - https://github.com/composer/installers/pull/269

And to add the new merge of composer/installers into your json. you can update the composer.json as per the The solution proposed here - https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project/pull/118. The same is explained in above code.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`davidbarratt/custom-installer`](https://github.com/davidbarratt/custom-installer) you can simply install any repo you want into any custom location you want by assigning it a totally custom type. In the sample below I used the custom types `"type": "foo-bar-foo"` and `"type": "bar-foo-bar"` to install two repos into two different custom locations.

Here's a working sample `composer.json`:

```
{
    "name": "myproject",
    "description": "myproject description",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "select2",
                "version": "4.0.3",
                "type": "foo-bar-foo",
                "source": {
                    "url": "https://github.com/select2/select2.git",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference": "tags/4.0.3"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "scrollmagic",
                "version": "v2.0.5",
                "type": "bar-foo-bar",
                "source": {
                    "url": "https://github.com/janpaepke/ScrollMagic.git",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference": "tags/v2.0.5"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "davidbarratt/custom-installer": "^1.0@alpha",
        "scrollmagic": "^2.0",
        "select2": "^4.0"
    },
    "extra": {
        "custom-installer": {
            "foo-bar-foo": "web/themes/custom/mytheme/lorem-ipsum/{$name}",
            "bar-foo-bar": "web/themes/custom/mytheme/dolor-sit-amet/{$name}"
        }
    }
}
```